# Angular 6 - How to get input value in component.ts from dynamically created input box within a table using *ngFor?

Tags: angular6

I need help in the following scenario: Let say if we created 10 rows for below HTML Then how we'll get all 10 rows Inserted First Name and Last Name Value on FORM SUBMIT in angular 6?

```
<form name="userForm">
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemList; let in = index">
      <td><input type="text" name="lastname-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="item.lastname"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="middlename-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="item.middlename"></td></tr></table></form>
```

Comment: <form name="userForm">
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemList; let in = index">
  <td><input type="text" name="lastname-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="item.lastname"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="middlename-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="item.middlename"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itemList` on submit of form.

```
<form name="userForm">
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of itemList; let in = index">
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="item.lastname">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="middlename-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="item.middlename">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" value="submit">
    </table>
</form>
<pre>
  {{this.itemList | json}}
</pre>
```

And in ts code..

```
      itemList = [{
        lastname: "",
        middlename: ""
      },
      {
        lastname: "",
        middlename: ""
      },
      {
        lastname: "",
        middlename: ""
      }]

      constructor() { }

      onSubmit() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Chatar SIngh, but this.itemList only give me array count. unable to retrieve input text box values.